# How to set world permissions to be the same as group permissions?

Tags: bash, shell, chmod

How would you go about changing permissions for a file or in a directory recursively in such a way that group permissions would be copied over to world permissions, with no other changes? For example, to go from this directory listing:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 septi septi 4096 Jun 29 01:14 example.d
-rw-r----- 1 septi septi    0 Jun 29 01:14 example.r
-rwxr-x--- 1 septi septi    0 Jun 29 01:14 example.x
```

...to:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 septi septi 4096 Jun 29 01:14 example.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 septi septi    0 Jun 29 01:14 example.r
-rwxr-xr-x 1 septi septi    0 Jun 29 01:14 example.x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`chmod(1)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/) (relevant parts extracted):

> **`-R`** Change the modes of the file hierarchies rooted in the files
>                instead of just the files themselves.

And:

> The symbolic mode is described by the following grammar:
>
> ```
> who    ::= a | u | g | o
> op     ::= + | - | =
> perm   ::= r | s | t | w | x | X | u | g | o
> ```
>
> The **`who`** symbols "**`u`**", "**`g`**", and "**`o`**" specify the user, group, and
>        other parts of the mode bits, respectively.  The **`who`** symbol **`a`** is
>        equivalent to **`ugo`**.
>
> The **`perm`** symbols represent the portions of the mode bits as follows:
>
> **`g`**       The group permission bits in the original mode of the file.

So for you:

```
chmod -R o=g *
```

Example:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-x---  2 carl  staff  68 Jun 28 10:25 example.d
-rw-r-----  1 carl  staff   0 Jun 28 10:25 example.r
-rwxr-x---  1 carl  staff   0 Jun 28 10:25 example.x
$ chmod -R o=g *
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 carl  staff  68 Jun 28 10:25 example.d
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff   0 Jun 28 10:25 example.r
-rwxr-xr-x  1 carl  staff   0 Jun 28 10:25 example.x
```

Comment: Note that `*` excludes files and directories whose names start with `.`. Depending on your requirements, you might prefer `chmod -R o=g .`